# Using limit on subquery

Tags: mysql

What have I done wrong?
It returns the following error:
`This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

The subquery works fine when I run it alone:

```
select * from emprego 
where base in 
(
  SELECT base FROM emprego me
  group by base
  order by sum(TIMEDIFF(me.data_demissao,me.data_admissao)) desc
  limit 1
)
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: It won't run when it's all together, it returns the error `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' `

Comment: Think the message is clear.

Comment: It's the latest MySQL version, so I guess I can't use sub queries.

Comment: You can use subqueries but not with limit.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query with self join

```
select e.* 
from emprego e
join  
(
  SELECT base FROM emprego me
  group by base
  order by sum(TIMEDIFF(me.data_demissao,me.data_admissao)) desc
  limit 1
) e1
on(e.base = e1.base)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from emprego
where base in
(
    select * from 
    (
        select base from emprego me
        group by base
        order by sum(TIMEDIFF(me.data_demissao, me.data_admissao)) desc
        limit 1
    ) as t
)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition of query:

```
SELECT *
FROM emprego E
INNER JOIN (SELECT E2.base
                 ,SUM(TIMEDIFF(E2.data_demissao, E2.data_admissao)) AS [duree]
            FROM emprego E2
            GROUP BY E2.base) D ON D.base = E.base
ORDER BY D.duree DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Hope this will help you to avoid the error during execution of the query.